# Can't install pulseaudio - broken packages

Tags: package-management, pulseaudio

I have:

- Operating System: Kubuntu 18.10
- KDE Plasma Version: 5.14.5
- Qt Version: 5.11.1
- KDE Frameworks Version: 5.52.0
- Kernel Version: 4.18.0-15-generic
- OS Type: 64-bit
- Processors: 4 × Intel® Pentium® CPU 4415U @ 2.30GHz
- Memory: 11.5 GiB of RAM

```
$ sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pulseaudio : Depends: libpulse0 (= 1:12.2-0ubuntu4) but 1:12.2-5~bionic1 is to be installed
              Depends: pulseaudio-utils but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: rtkit but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

```
$ apt-cache policy libpulse0
libpulse0:
  Installed: 1:12.2-5~bionic1
  Candidate: 1:12.2-5~bionic1
  Version table:
 *** 1:12.2-5~bionic1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:12.2-0ubuntu4 500
        500 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete output of `apt-cache policy libpulse0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `1:12.2-5~bionic1` version of `libpulse0` is not from official repositories. You probably installed it from somewhere else.

I suggest downgrading the version using Synaptic.

Select the package and then use "Package" menu to set the correct `1:12.2-0ubuntu4` version.

Comment: I have forced libpulse0 to use 1:12.2-5~bionic1 in Synaptic package manager but it does not show in terminal when trying to install pulseaudio - i get the same error as if not taking effect.

Comment: Change it to use `1:12.2-0ubuntu4` version instead.